# CGFloat and types, How do I do Math correctly?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to keep an enum of app properties, that looks like:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

public enum AppDimensions:CGFloat {

    case TOP_BAR_HEIGHT             = 183.0
    case PROFILE_IMAGE_HEIGHT       = 200.0
    case TOOLBAR_HEIGHT             = 70.00
    case CATEGORY_TABLE_OFFSET_Y    = 210.00
}

var i:CGFloat = CGFloat(self.view.bounds.height) - CGFloat(AppDimensions.TOOLBAR_HEIGHT)
```

Gives me an error: 
Binary operator '-' cannot be applied to...

How do I do this correctly?

Comment: Eh, sorry, why doesn't XCode allow the user to copy and paste error messages

Comment: Good question! [bugreport](http://bugreport.apple.com/)! The solution is to go the Report Navigator (right end tool), reveil the error, you still can't copy but you can drag the error to a text window. See here: Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat' with an argument list of type '(AppDimensions)'

Answer (score 1):

Swift error messages can be challenging so:
Create intermediate statements to isolate the error:

```
let toolBarHeight = CGFloat(AppDimensions.TOOLBAR_HEIGHT)
let boundsHeight = CGFloat(self.view.bounds.height)
var i:CGFloat = boundsHeight - toolBarHeight
```

This will produce an error on the first statement that is more helpful:

> Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat` with an argument or type '(AppDimensions)'

The solution:

```
let x = CGFloat(AppDimensions.TOOLBAR_HEIGHT.rawValue)
```

Intermediate statement are a debugging friend and good code as well as are also really good names.

Comment: Thanks so much, yes, I am newer to swift.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you missed `.rawValue`? Try this:

```
var i:CGFloat = CGFloat(self.view.bounds.height) - CGFloat(AppDimensions.TOOLBAR_HEIGHT.rawValue)
```